# Checkbox inside user control in repeater doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net

I have user control inside a page with single repeater. The problem is when this control is placed inside repeater check box doesn't fire CheckedChanged event. If this would be a dynamically added control I would check whether CheckedCanged event has a handle assigned in Init() but here the event is specified in ascx so I imagine asp.net is responsible for doing all the assignments in right place. I'm lost here :/

By the way. Placing single checkbox inside repeater doesn't fire to. But I can at least use OnItemCommand there

User Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="QuoteContainer.ascx.cs" Inherits="EhdSite.Controls.QuoteContainer" %>
<asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="trQuoteRow">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbxConfirm" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CbxConfirmCheckedChanged" />
</asp:TableRow>
```

Page

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upQuotes" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptQuotes">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <ehd:QuoteContainer 
                        runat="server" 
                        ID="qcQuote" 
                        RowCssClass="rowStyle" 
                        HighlightedRowCssClass="selectedRowStyle" 
                        Quote="<%# Container.DataItem %>" 
                        OnQuoteSelectedChanged="QuoteSelectedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: In which event do you bind the repeater? If you do it in the OnPreRender it definitively won't work! I need to see the codebehind of the usercontrol and the page, or at least the part of it concerning the repeater and the checkobx...

Comment: I moved it to Page_Init and it started working. Could you explain it as answer to this question so I could give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the event-chain in ASP.Net, this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) helps to understand it.

The .Net framework resolves the `ViewState` between the `Init`- and the `Load`-event. So if the control is not there after the `Init`-event, it's `ViewState` will never be loaded and also it's events will never be fired.

This can get quite tricky at times, especially if one dynamically loaded control should affect the loading of another one...